# Not all images on html page loading without browser refresh

Tags: html, css, image, loading

I have a simple html page with an image gallery. Sometimes not all the images will load. To me it seems to be random, never the same images. When the images do not load I refresh the page and they load instantly, it is usually only one or two images per page. Here is the website link.
http://www.kayleighwhite.org/engagements-sweethearts-017#gallery

This is the html for the images

```
 <div class="gallery_one" style="background-image: url(images/portfolio/engagements-sweethearts/0168.JPG); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;">
        <img src="images/portfolio/portfolio.gif" width="960" height="639" class="gal" alt="gallery">
        </div>
```

The css

```
.gallery_one    {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}


.gal    {
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

The image not loading is the background image. The portfolio.gif is just a transparent image that is layered over the top. Like I said though this is just random.

I'm not saying that 0168.JPG is not loading, cause tonight it is. But if you just keep clicking the "next" link eventually there will be a page that does not load all the images. I know that this is hard to determine the cause, but does anyone see anything wrong with this html or css that could cause this problem? Or any knowledge of such problems?

By the way I tested this on firefox and chrome on two different computers, both running windows 7. Same random results.

Comment: Open the element inspector  over the image that didn't load properly, it could help you.

Comment: I have gone through you gallery and all the images loaded to me perfectly :-/